# Change size of font of subscript of underbrace in align environment

Tags: align, fontsize, subscripts

I would like to have a bigger subscript S under the underbrace in the following equation and appreciate your help.

```
\begin{align}
K&=\frac{E}{(1+i)^r}\cdot \underbrace{\left (1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{3\cdot g}}+...+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{(n-1)\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n\cdot g}}\right )}_S\\
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `_{\textstyle S}`, perhaps adding `\mathstrut` to give a bit more room.

Here a couple of examples, the second uses `multlined` (which requires `mathtools`) for splitting the big underbraced object into two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
K=\frac{E}{(1+i)^r}\cdot 
  \underbrace{\left(
    1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2\cdot g}}
     +\frac{1}{(1+i)^{3\cdot g}}
     +\dots
    +\frac{1}{(1+i)^{(n-1)\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n\cdot g}}\right )
  }_{\textstyle S\mathstrut}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
K=\frac{E}{(1+i)^r}\cdot 
  \underbrace{
    \begin{multlined}[t]
    \biggl(
      1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2\cdot g}}
       +\frac{1}{(1+i)^{3\cdot g}}
       +\dots
    \\
      +\frac{1}{(1+i)^{(n-1)\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n\cdot g}}
    \biggr)
    \end{multlined}
  }_{\textstyle S\mathstrut}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Notes:** never use `align` for a single line display; avoid `...` and prefer `\dots`.

I'd also write `2g`, `3g` and so on, without `\cdot`, unless this is not ordinary multiples and `\cdot` denotes a special action.

Comment: Thank you egreg. I like the multiline version and appreciate your note on ... and \cdot

Answer (score 1):

It does not fit on my page but here you are:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    K&=\frac{E}{(1+i)^r}\cdot \underbrace{\left (1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{3\cdot g}}+...+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{(n-1)\cdot g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{n\cdot g}}\right )}_{\mathlarger{S}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Maybe better:

```
\begin{align*}
    K&=\frac{E}{(1+i)^r}\biggl(\underbrace{1+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{2g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{3g}}+\dots+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{(n-1)g}}+\frac{1}{(1+i)^{ng}}}_{\mathlarger{S}}\biggr)
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Feel free to do `_{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{S}}}}` and alike.